# Adding li to ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Not getting an idea how to add each values to following html snippet using jquery ,its a bootstrap html.

I have a list like this.trying to add each values inside ul.

The code is

```
$(".cookieul").on("click",function(){
 var list = "abc,cvb,zxcv,ert,wer";
});




<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cookieul">Set favourite</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="cookieul">
    <li><a href="#">Set<span id="d">del</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to add additional li elements to the existing ul? Where do the values come from? What event would trigger this process?

Comment: yes,I need to create li inside ul using the above value.I have all values in my jquery code.Its happening when  I click on a button (cookieul).Button alreday available in the code

Comment: Please show the relevant part of your existing JS code.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Devasnsh_Kumar/nzojr76d/

Comment: are you wanted to do something like this or other think

Comment: @Devansh ,abc,cvb,zxcv,ert,wer the all string is adding.I am trying a  comma separated value to li

Comment: are you vanting to split your string on the basis of comma and then add each value in list

Comment: @aniltc like this http://fiddle.jshell.net/Devasnsh_Kumar/nzojr76d/1/

Answer (score 0):

Updated.

Probably this is what you wanna achieve?

```
var str_list = "abc,cvb,zxcv,ert,wer";
var list = str_list.split(',');

$.each(list, function(item){
    $('ul').append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the string. Moreover, `cookieul` is not the class. It seems to be the `id` of your `ul`. So better be sure about the `id` of the button you are clicking.

```js
var list = "abc,cvb,zxcv,ert,wer";
var arr = list.split(",");

$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    for (var item in arr) {
     $('ul#cookieul').append('<li>' + arr[item] + '</li>');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="cookieul">
 <li><a href="#">Set<span id="d">del</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
</ul>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" />
```

Comment: Downvoter: At least let me know where I have gone wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this way

```
var list = "abc,cvb,zxcv,ert,wer";

     list = list.split(',');



    for (var a in list){

         $('#cookieul').append('<li>'+list[a]+'</li>');
    }
```